# Python 2.7 -- Can't pass a parameter from main file to a module class

Tags: python

I will simplify this to explain.  Let's say I have a main file and an engine module.
Why can't I pass Corridor and Weapon to **init** in the Engine class without receiving an error message?  Namely, 'Name Error: Corridor is not defined'.  I did get this to work when everything was in a single file...  Thanks in advance for your advice!

```
#In the main file
import engine
a_engine = engine.Engine(Corridor, Weapon)

#In the engine module
class Engine(object):

   def __init__(self, room, weapon):
       self.room = room.room()
       self.weapon = weapon.weapon()
```

Comment: Python is trying to tell you something. Hint: The problem isn't in the code you've shown us. The problem is that Corridor isn't defined.

Answer (score 1):

The `Engine` class has no idea what Corridor is. Its still in the namespace of the `engine` module. If you did the following:

```
from engine import Engine
a_engine = Engine(Corridor, Weapon)
```

it should then work for you. What this does is "hoists" the `Engine` class into the wider namespace of your main file. Typically, you don't want to do this.

So, you need to make `Engine` aware of `Corridor` and `Weapon`. The best practices way is to define them in a different module, and in `engine.py`, do the following `from extra import Corridor, Weapon`. Then in main, you can do `a_engine = engine.Engine(extra.Corridor, extra.Weapon)`.

Comment: Thanks. I am still not sure if that would work.  Although you might be thinking along a different line.  Let's say I create the extra module and do this: Corridor = 'Corridor'.  The code will break since I am passing in a string.  And I can't do Corridor = Corridor.

Comment: How would `Corridor` and `Weapon` be hoisted from `engine` if you are only importing `Engine` into the main namespace? (In fact, the whole point of `from x import y` is that you *only* get `y` and don't pollute the calling namespace with extraneous names from `x`.) And if `Corridor` and `Weapon` are indeed defined in `engine`, then your "best practices" suggestion doesn't strike me as much better, if at all, than simply `a_engine = engine.Engine(engine.Corridor, engine.Weapon)` and dispensing with any additional modules.

Comment: I made the assumption they had defined Corridor and Weapon in their main file. I've done exactly that.

Comment: But if `Corridor` and `Weapon` were defined in the main file, then OP never would have gotten the error message that they did. In any case, no matter where those names are defined, your original suggestion won't work.